# Why @LoadBalanced annotation is necessary while using RestTemplate and eureka server for service discovery

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have two microservices deployed and a `eureka server`. The microservices are eureka clients, viz, `eureka-client-1` and `eureka-client-2` respectively.

Using, `service discovery`, I want to call an API from `eureka-client-1` of `eureka-client-2`.

Following is the supported code and configurations:

1. **`discovery-server` (eureka server) configuration:**

> ```
> server:
>   port: 8761
>
> eureka:
>   client:
>     fetch-registry: false
>     register-with-eureka: false
>   
> spring:
>   application:
>     name: discovery-server
> ```

2. **`eureka-client-1` and `eureka-client-2` have same configurations:**

> ```
> eureka:   
>   client:
>     service-url:
>        defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
> ```

3. In `eureka-client-1` I am using `RestTemplate` to communicate with the `eureka-client-2`

**Notice that I have currently commented the `LoadBalanced` annotation.**

```
   @Bean
   // @LoadBalanced
   public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
     return new RestTemplate();
   }
```

4. I access the api of `eureka-client-2` as follows:

   ```
   restTemplate.getForObject(
            "http://EUREKA-CLIENT-2/api/v1/check/{customerId}", Response.class, customer.getId());
   ```

When I deploy and test the application, I am getting `UnknownHostException` for `EUREKA-CLIENT-2`. But, as soon as I **enable the annotation** `@LoadBalanced` everything works fine and `eureka-client-1` can successfully communicate with `eureka-client-2`.

My question is: Why `@LoadBalanced` annotation is absolutely compulsory? If I have deployed only single instances of each microservices, why can't the `discovery-server` return the information of the only service with given name that is deployed? And even if same service is deployed multiple times, why it can't internally apply the loadbalancing algorithm? Why the client has to specifically add the annotation

Comment: Because of the annotation, rest template gets instrumented so the it uses eureka, otherwise it has no way of talking to eureka no matter how many instances there are

Comment: Alternatively, you could use an injected discovery client to get the instances of the service from Eureka, select an instance on your own and do a direct call with a REST template against it, but unless you're doing something very custom, it's going to be much more practical to use SC LB.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is, you can either inject a loadBalancer client or a discovery client to do the same thing. Just remember while using a loadBalancer client you get to use the choose() method based on which your LB will choose among the multiple instances registered with eureka in a round robin fashion but if you are using a discovery client then instead of getting a single instance you will get a list of instances. See in these two cases we are actually giving rest template a load balancer from our end. But with the other approach as in not specifying a client LB, the rest template is confused between which instance it has to call(assuming there will be scaling of instances in future). So the rest template is complaining us to provide a LB from our end.
Also adding to it the eureka client dependency will internally fetch a spring cloud load balancer even if we do not mention the cloud load balancer dependency explicitly. So as soon as the rest template sees this @LoadBalanced annotation, it will treat it as a client side load balancer and starts to fetch instances from eureka in a round robin manner.